# opengraph tags not working on components [Vuejs, vue-meta]

Tags: vue.js, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

**The case:**

I'm working on a vuejs app that has a mid complexity route structure, there's a view on that system (i'm going to explain later on this question) that renders a news articles with data consumed from a wordpress backend. The problem is that when i paste the url of that article on facebook, it doesn't shows the image of that article, or the title, or the description, nothing.

**Proyect structure and what have i tried this far**

the proyect routes structure is as follows:

Main page articles

```
<Root>
  <App>
    <Article>  router-view /article/:id
```

I also have an article view that is a nested route of a component called League

```
<Root>
  <App>
    <League> router-view /league
      <Article>  router-view /league/article/:id
```

the component rendered on both article views is the same, it makes a get http request with axios that brings info i render on the component, such as title, description, body of the article and image.

I setted the meta tags for that view using vue-meta, like this:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  props: ['id'],
  data() {
    return {
      article: '',
  },
  created() {
    this.loadComponentData();
  },
  computed: {
    title() {
      if (this.article) {
        return this.article.title.rendered;
      } return 'loading...';
    },
    description() {
      if (this.article) {
        let des = this.article.acf.short_description.replace(/<\/p>/g, '');
        des = des.replace(/<p>/g, '');
        return des;
      } return 'loading...';
    },
    image() {
      if (this.article) {
        return this.article.acf.cover_image;
      } return '';
    },
  },
  methods: {

    async loadComponentData() {
      try {
        const article = await axios.get(`http://requestURLHere/wp-json/wp/v2/article/${this.id}`);
        this.article = article.data;
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e);
      }
    }
  },
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        {
          property: 'og:title',
          content: this.title,
        },
        {
          property: 'og:type',
          content: 'website',
        },
        {
          property: 'og:description',
          content: this.description,
        },
        {
          property: 'og:image',
          content: this.image,
        },
        {
          property: 'og:url',
          content: `http://realServerURL/article/${this.id}`,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**The problem**

When i copy any of the articles url and paste it into facebook, it doesnt show the title of the document, or the description, or the image, just the title i setted on the index html document and the favicon on the website, even when the open graph meta tags are actually rendered. Other weird thing that happens is that facebook is showing what i just said ONLY with the articles that are not a child route, with the child routes it doesnt show anything at all

If you need more info, just let me know

Comment: where are they rendered? client side or server side?

Comment: They're client side rendered

Comment: facebook does not parse javascript. you have to render them server side.

Comment: [Awatatah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466145) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68658537) saying "I address this in an article on how to achieve this -> [Meta Tags and how to server side render them with Express + Vue.js](https://juanlaporte.com/2021/08/04/meta-tags-and-how-to-server-side-render-them-with-express-vue-js/)"